# DomainContext class is not created in a RIA services class library solution

Tags: silverlight, wcf-ria-services

I have created a RIA services class library project and things are not going as I expected. The problem is that when I add domain service classes to the server project, the corresponding domain context classes are not generated on the client project.

I start by creating a new project of type *WCF RIA services class library*. The generated solution has two projects: `RIAServicesLibrary1` (the Silverlight class library project) and `RIAServicesLibrary1.Web` (the class library that will hold the services).

Then I add a new project item to `RIAServicesLibrary1.Web` of type *DomainServiceClass*. I add a sample method so that the resulting class code is:

```
namespace RIAServicesLibrary1.Web
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting;
    using System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Server;


    // TODO: Create methods containing your application logic.
    [EnableClientAccess()]
    public class DomainService1 : DomainService
    {
        [Invoke]
        void DoSomething()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Then I generate the whole solution and... nothing happens on the client project. The `Generated_Code` folder is empty, and the domain context object for the service is not here.

Funny enough, if I add a new item of type *Authentication domain service*, it works as expected: the file `RIAServicesLibrary1.Web.g.cs` is created on the client project, containing the `AuthenticationDomainService1` class as expected.

So what's happening here? Am I doing something wrong?

**Note**: I am using Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate RTM and WCF RIA services 1.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change it to:

```
[Invoke]
public void DoSomething()
{
}
```

Not having 'public' means there was nothing to generate.

Comment: (O___O) I feel soooo stupid... thank you for your reply!
(WTF? I need to wait 4 minutes before I can accept your answer)